# Login issues with PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having issues with my login procedure.

It keeps failing even when I type in the correct credentials.

Any idea what could be wrong?

**jQuery**

```
$loginForm.click(function (e) {
    if ($.trim($("#password").val()).length === 0) {
        alert('You must provide valid input');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('#login_header, #password, #sendlogin, #pass_title').hide()
        $.post("assets/login.php",{ password:$('#password').val() },function(data)
        {
            if(data=='yes')
            {
                alert("Login success.");
                // alert($('#password').val());
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Login failure.");
                // alert($('#password').val());
            }
        }
    )}
});
```

**login.php**

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<?php
$password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'],ENT_QUOTES);

$sql="SELECT id FROM login WHERE password='".$password."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo "yes";
    echo $password;
}
else
{
    echo "no"; 
}
?>
```

I get the following error message now:

[image]

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injections!

Comment: I've updated it. Is it better now?

Comment: Be careful with adding things like htmlspecialchars() on existing data. If the passes are entered in the past without this will result in non-matching passwords (non-escaped entries vs escaped inputs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in your login.php, $pass should be $password:

```
<?
$password=$_POST['password']; 

//now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE pass='".$password."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 

//if password exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no"; 
}
```

EDIT: Added PDO example:

If you get it working (think the problem lies in the name of the fields/database) it would be nice to rewrite it using PDO because, as pointed out by others, mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP version 5.5.

Using PDO it should look like:

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbName = '';
$dbUser = '';
$dbPass = '';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass); 
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `login` WHERE `pass` = ? LIMIT 1');
$sth->execute(array($password));
if(!$results = $sth->fetchAll()) {
    // no results
}
var_dump($results);
```

(for completeness I added the connection part also).

Comment: don't forget the $passord sql escaping

Comment: I am hoping this is only example code (without security measures) to test the malfunctioning.

Comment: See the updated code, I've even renamed the table in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Try debugging because we're missing a lot of details about for example the data in your table, the content of the password field you're posting. First of all: do a print_r($_POST);die; to see if there is any data posted, than compare this data with the value in the database. Etc etc.

Comment: The query failed; Are you 100% sure the table is named 'login', there is a column named 'id' and the password field is named 'password'? Test your query first using, for example, PHPmyAdmin.

Answer (score -1):

Get the num rows and then fetch it.

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<?php
$password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'],ENT_QUOTES);

$sql="SELECT id FROM login WHERE password='".$password."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// this line move to below.
//$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "yes";
    echo $password;
}
else {
    echo "no"; 
}
?>
```

- Dont use mysql_query and friends, because this function will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5 [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)
- So try to use PDO ([link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)